# Designing legs for table - what software to use?

Tags: design-principles

Trying do estimate the exact points of connecting vertical parts of legs with the base of the legs (horizontal part) and with the countertop. Later legs will be cut out in steal, so before I do it, I wanna make sure that this whole structure will stand still. Is there any free software which allows to create a precise model? Will SketchUp do the job?

[image]

Comment: This does not seem a **Graphics** Design question to me. You are better off using a real CAD program.

Comment: What do you need the model to tell you?

Comment: You've three embedded questions here really: 1) best free CAD tool for 2D & 3D work 2) level of precision possible with said tool given specific use-case and 3) statics / dynamics calculation engine within said program to output correct balance point ranges given leg / foot dimensions, table dimensions and material density. 1) DraftSight is a good, free 2 & 3D CAD, as is OnShape. 2) Both will provide a high precision level. 3) Paid OnShape plug-ins might do the physics calcs, but I'd guess that'll end up being you, a calculator, and a statics reference book from the library.

Comment: You *could* model it in Blender and do a bullet physics simulation there to test balance points, but that would only be an approximation.

Comment: Blender - [https://www.blender.org/], Draftsight - [https://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight-cad-software/free-download/] OnShape - [https://www.onshape.com/]

Comment: @GerardFalla MANY THANKS, that really was a great help. Sorry for a late reply.